# Why transformed matrices give the same solutions?

Tags: matrices

> For any [augmented matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix), three elementary row operations are:
>
> 1. interchange two rows of a matrix,
>
> 2. change a row by adding to it a multiple of another row, and
>
> 3. multiply each element in a row by the same nonzero number.
>
> Since these operations are reversible, any solution to the transformed system of equations will also be a solution to the original system.

How "reversible" implies same solutions for both matrices?

Comment: duplicate (somewhat) of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509130/proof-of-elementary-row-operations-for-matrices?rq=1?

Comment: @SujaanKunalan, Thanks.